# Creating class instances iteratively in loop

Tags: python, class, iteration

I want to create multiple instances of a class using a for loop and giving them different names:

```
robot_list = []
for i in range(10):
    robot_list.append(robot + str(i) = BasicNavigator())
```

This doesn't work, and currently, I am doing this:

```
robot_list = []
robot0 = BasicNavigator()
robot_list.append(robot0)
robot1 = BasicNavigator()
robot_list.append(robot1)
robot2 = BasicNavigator()
robot_list.append(robot2)
```

But I would like to make it more dynamic, so I choose e.g. 7 robots, it creates 7 instances, you know?

Any way of doing this?

Comment: What is `robot` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to store the instance alongside the name of that instance, using a dictionary is the best choice.

This can help you create the number of instances you want and store them inside a list.

```
class Robot():
  def talk(self):
    return "Hi, I am a robot"

robots_num = 7
robots = {}
for i in range(robots_num):
  robots[f"robot_{i}"] = Robot()

print(robots["robot_0"].talk())
```

Output-

```
Hi, I am a robot
```